# GNUstep installation

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

How will I install GNUStep in Linux ?

Comment: The compiler can't find either your headers or the dynamic libraries (hard to tell exactly from what you described here). Play around with the `-I`, `-L` and `-l` compiler flags.

Comment: @SusantPalai Don't give us a vague description of the error message.  Copy the error message, edit your post, and paste in the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you path the start up scripts. They were necessary to be invoked once per shell before running any GNUstep binary. Something like this

. /usr/local/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh

(Don't miss the first dot and a space after it)

You can install things directly from trunk. Here are some useful scripts from Etoile project. It fetch the svn and install things for you. You may also look into the script and ignore the Etoile bits.

http://svn.gna.org/svn/etoile/trunk/Etoile/BuildScripts/

AFAICR, it is not a good idea to use distributor's packages, they were badly maintained, broken and should be avoided.

And you should ditch gcc for clang.

Also, take a look at Philippe Roussel's package repository. I've never use them.

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnustep/2012-10/msg00034.html